# Transform.scale() not scalling the given spaces

Tags: css, react-native, animation, scale, css-transforms

I have used [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) API to scale my center item of `FlatList`twice the size and it's working perfectly. The problem is the margins or paddings are not being scaled causing center item to overlap with previous and next item.

**My Animated.View**

```
<Animated.View
        style={{
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          marginLeft: 6,
          marginRight: 6,
          width: 70,
          height: 70,
          borderRadius: 35,
          borderColor: 'white',
          position: 'relative',
          borderWidth: 2,
          transform: [
            {
              scale: animatedValue.interpolate({
                inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
                outputRange: [1, 2, 1],
                extrapolate: 'clamp'
              })
            }]
        }}>
....other components
</Animated.View>
```

I have also tried putting all components inside `Animated.View` and giving them margin or padding. Still no success.